Переход между формами по нажатию кнопки
Мне нужно, что бы при нажатии на кнопку - у меня переходила смена окна на форму.
Этот код работает, но при его срабатывание видно как прячется прошлое окно и появляется новое, как сделать, что бы этого не было видно?
private void Steam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        SteamForm steamForm = new SteamForm();
        steamForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        steamForm.Location = Location;
        steamForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }


"как сделать, что бы этого не было видно" - логично, не работать с формами? Вы хотите сделать одностраничное приложение, где внутри одного окна будет меняться его контент. Собственно это и делайте, не новое окно, а полная перерисовка контента в текущем окне.

Вам следует уточнить ваш вопрос. Что вам не нравится в вашем коде — что первое окно не сразу скрывается? А какое поведение вы ожидаете?

Мне не нравится в моем коде то, что когда происходит сама смена, видно глазу что окно удаляется и появляется новое. В том же Python (PySide6) Я это исправлял используя QStackedWidget.

Форма - это, по сути, окно. То есть закрывая одну форму и открывая другую - вы закрываете одно окно и открываете другое. То, что вам надо, судя по вашему описанию, это не закрытие/открытие форм, а замену содержимого формы. Что то типа этого https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584902/change-content-in-a-windows-form

Большое спасибо, помогли.
